# API response is array of arrays. The first array being the key in key-value pair of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Here's what my process would be. I would take the first array, assign the values as object keys to my template. I would then want use that template, assign the next array's elements as values to it, and then push that to the final response object. I would then continue to do that until I've reached the end of the response array. I essentially want to convert this to JSON, using the first response array's elements as values for all.

Here's the response:

```
[
  [
    "POP",
    "GEONAME",
    "state"
  ],
  [
    "4863300",
    "Alabama",
    "01"
  ],
  [
    "741894",
    "Alaska",
    "02"
  ],
  [
    "6931071",
    "Arizona",
    "04"
  ],
  [
    "2988248",
    "Arkansas",
    "05"
  ],
  [
    "39250017",
    "California",
    "06"
  ]
]
```

Here's the output I want (The keys are always are the first response index)

```
{
  {
    "POP": "4863300"
    "GEONAME": "Alabama"
    "state": "01"
  }
  {
    "POP": "741894"
    "GEONAME": "Alaska"
    "state": "02"
  },
  {
    "POP": "6931071"
    "GEONAME": "Arizona"
    "state": "04"
  },
  {
    "POP": "2988248"
    "GEONAME": "Arkansas"
    "state": "05"
  },
  {
    "POP": "39250017"
    "GEONAME": "California"
    "state": "06"
  }
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
function modifyArrayResponse(response) {
  // Create template (Assign keys)
  let template = {};
  let keys = response[0];

  // Assign keys to template
  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    template[keys[i]] = template[i];
  }

  // Use the template (Assign values)



  // Return modified response
}
```

Comment: what you wanted is not a valid JSON though :-)

Comment: Why is it not valid JSON?

Comment: Objects have to have keys, `{ { ... } }` doesn't make sense, but `[ { ... } ]` does, so does: `{ "foo": { ... } }`.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is not valid. You have `{}` around the whole thing, but that's for objects, which need to be `key: value` pairs. What you should desire is an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "POP": "4863300"
    "GEONAME": "Alabama"
    "state": "01"
  }
  {
    "POP": "741894"
    "GEONAME": "Alaska"
    "state": "02"
  },
  {
    "POP": "6931071"
    "GEONAME": "Arizona"
    "state": "04"
  },
  {
    "POP": "2988248"
    "GEONAME": "Arkansas"
    "state": "05"
  },
  {
    "POP": "39250017"
    "GEONAME": "California"
    "state": "06"
  }
]
```

The code to create this needs to loop over all the elements after the first.

```js
function modifyArrayResponse(response) {
  const keys = response[0];
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < response.length; i++) {
    const obj = {};
    keys.forEach((key, index) => obj[key] = response[i][index]);
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

var input = [
  ["POP", "GEONAME", "state"],
  ["4863300", "Alabama", "01"],
  ["741894", "Alaska", "02"],
  ["6931071", "Arizona", "04"],
  ["2988248", "Arkansas", "05"],
  ["39250017", "California", "06"]
];

console.log(modifyArrayResponse(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
var oData = [
  [
    "POP",
    "GEONAME",
    "state"
  ],
  [
    "4863300",
    "Alabama",
    "01"
  ],
  [
    "741894",
    "Alaska",
    "02"
  ],
  [
    "6931071",
    "Arizona",
    "04"
  ],
  [
    "2988248",
    "Arkansas",
    "05"
  ],
  [
    "39250017",
    "California",
    "06"
  ]
];

var oResult = [];
var columns = null;
oData.forEach(function(data) {
  if (columns === null) {
    columns = data;
  } else {
    var oEntry = {};
    oResult.push(oEntry);
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
      oEntry[columns[i]] = d;
    });
  }
});

console.log(oResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `shift()` to get and remove column names and then `map()` remainder of array and use `reduce()` on columns to create each object

```js
let cols = data.shift()

let res = data.map(arr => cols.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[c] = arr[i], a), {}))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
  var data = [
    ["POP", "GEONAME", "state"],
    ["4863300", "Alabama", "01"],
    ["741894", "Alaska", "02"],
    ["6931071", "Arizona", "04"],
    ["2988248", "Arkansas", "05"],
    ["39250017", "California", "06"]
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: @Barmar probably right, cleaned up with a simple reduce

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the keys and values into separate arrays, and then iterate over the values with `Array.prototype.map` and construct the objects with `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const data=[["POP","GEONAME","state"],["4863300","Alabama","01"],["741894","Alaska","02"],["6931071","Arizona","04"],["2988248","Arkansas","05"],["39250017","California","06"]];

const [keys, ...vals] = data;

const result = vals.map(item => item.reduce((all,v,i) => (all[keys[i]] = item[i], all), {}));

console.log(result);
```